# Enriching serilog logs with EventId

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I would like to enrich my logs with eventId so that I can easily find certain type of events.
I know that the .netCore already has the [EventId](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.eventid?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) struct that is passed to the [Ilogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

So when I do this in my code:

```
_logger.LogInformation(_events.TestEvent,"Test logged.");
```

I would like to get the Id inside the eventId struct to the properties of the log.
I tryed writing my on enricher of type ILogEventEnricher but there is no way to access the EventId struct from Serilog.Events.LogEvent class.

Is there an other way to do this?

Od do I have to push an custom property to logs like this every time?

```
using(LogContext.PushProperty("EventId", _events.SendingEmailSmarEmailing.Id))
   _logger.LogInformation("Test polling service runned.");
```

Comment: Its seemingly there https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/28

Comment: Yeah but how to access it inside the ILogEventEnricher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use middleware to automatically push properties.
That requires 3 changes; an LogEventEnricher, Middleware to push properties for each request, and finally those needs to be registered.
It works by the middleware getting the eventenricher injected, which it uses to pushproperties before awaiting _next(), which call your controllers endpoint handler

```cs
 public class CommonEventEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
    {
        private readonly YourOperationContext _operationContext;

        public CommonEventEnricher(YourOperationContext context)
        {
            _operationContext = context;
        }

        public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
        {
            logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("EventId", _operationContext.EventId));
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class LoggingInterceptorMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public LoggingInterceptorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogEventEnricher logEventEnricher)
        {
            using (LogContext.Push(logEventEnricher))
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then finally:

```cs
applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<LoggingInterceptorMiddleware>()
```

```cs
serviceCollection.AddScoped<ILogEventEnricher, CommonEventEnricher>();
```

in your startup

Comment: Is that gonna work outside the asp.net ? I'd like to log events inside other type of apps, mostly worker services.

Comment: Yes, the approach is still the same outside asp, though support for interceptors (like aspnet middleware) is needed. Similarly, you would of course also need to control the scope (for IoC) yourself. Aspnet core automatically creates a scope for each request, so you could do something very similar, and create a scope for each independent "action" your workers perform